# Pre-load python libraries in Nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I have a web app with JavaScript front end and python back end. The user writes a phrase, clicks a button, python parses the sentence (natural language processing) and sends data back to the client. I use SpaCy for natural language processing. SpaCy takes a long time to load, so I wanted to know if I could pre-load SpaCy in NodeJS when I start the server (vs. importing SpaCy every time I spawn the python file - which is what I do now, See code below).
Thanks!

JavaScript code:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('run_command_request', async (data) => {
        let output_str = await run_python_command(data);
        socket.emit('run_command_complete');
    });
});


async function run_python_command(data) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var py = spawn(python_executable, ['./run_command.py']); //PYTHON FILE CALLED EVERY TIME A USER CLICKS A BUTTON
    var python_output_string ='';
    py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    py.stdin.end();
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        py.stdout.on('end', function() {
            res(python_output_string);
        });
    });
}
```

Python code:

```
import spacy #############   THIS STEP TAKES FOREVER    #############   
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") 
doc = nlp(tc)
verb = [token.lemma_ for token in doc if token.pos_ == "VERB"]
print(verb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your python program into a server.  Your nodejs program could start it once when it starts.  Then, instead of spawning each time, you just send it a request with your JSON data and wait for its response.

For simplicity, you might even make the python program an http server (on a known, local, non-publicly routed port) and you could just send it an http request whenever you want it to run the natural language parsing on a phrase.

Think of the python program more like a service that is running and available to handle requests anytime.  That way you only pay the startup cost once.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to program a server on Python? I'm new to programming so any links / tutorials / etc would be very helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: @Felipe - I don't know Python frameworks myself, but here's a place to start: https://geekflare.com/python-frameworks-for-apis/.  You could design a POST request that accepts the JSON input as the body and returns the natural language result.